# data frame append is putting the first row as NA, then adding it to the end with correct value as a new row

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to fill in a data frame using append.
The price row gets filled in with NA and it as a new row price is added at the end with the correct vales
When I load the data frame and print it I have
 Price,Time,open,close,smallest,biggest,bvol,svol,isvalid,id1,sell1,vol1,id2,sell2,vol2,id3,sell3,vol3,dummy1,dummy2,dummy3

when I fill it in the data frame changes to
 Price,Time,open,close,smallest,biggest,bvol,svol,isvalid,id1,sell1,vol1,id2,sell2,vol2,id3,sell3,vol3,dummy1,dummy2,dummy3, Price

where the first price row is filled in with NAs and the new price row added at the end gets the correct value.

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet? A snippet of code is worth a thousand explanations of it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].